# iterate at a function input in python

Tags: python, dictionary

i need to transfer the values in a dict (dict1 in the example below) to a function **in an element by element manner** (func1 in the example below, the function can not be changed)

```
def func1(input1,input2,input3):
    print input1
    print input2
    print input3

dict1={"a":1,"b":2,"c":3}
keys=["a","b","c"]
func1(dict1["a"],dict1["b"],dict1["c"])
```

How can i improve the last line with the help of array keys?
i have tried

```
func1([dict[key] for key in keys])
```

and

```
func1(dict[key] for key in keys)
```

Comment: Your first option is almost right, but you can do something like `[dict1[k] for k in dict1.keys()]`, so you don't need an additional list

Comment: @Gianluca: that won't preserve the order, though, and if the OP doesn't care about a particular order, then `*dict1.values()` is better anyway.  Please don't try to answer questions in comments.

Comment: These are to be used as function arguments, so I'd say balance of probability is that order does matter.

Comment: @gianluca you should use `dict1.values()` in that case, but you should call `keys` to iterate over keys, just use `for k in dict1`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `func1([dict[key1] for key in keys])` almost worked, you just need to unpack it before sending it to the function using `*`

```
func1(*[dict1[key] for key in keys])
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you were asking for improvements. You didn't leave much room for them but some might say that not creating a throw-away list might count as one:

```
func1(*(dict1[key] for key in keys))
```

Obviously, as improvements go this one is very minor.